# segmentation fault unix shell

Tags: c, shell, unix, segmentation-fault

I have an assignment for school where I have to create a shell which can do the following:

1. read incoming command, parse each part of command
2. fork child process and execute each command without (< > >> |)
3. successfully execute each command with <, >, >>
4. successfully execute each command with |

I am seriously lost... I am new to shell and I have no clue on what to do from here.
My code gives me an error stating `segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_ARG 10

int main()
{
        char line [256];
        char prompt[] = "sh2 % ";
        char command[256], *args[MAX_ARG];
        int pid;
        char status;
        int i;

        /* spit out the prompt */
        printf("%s", prompt );

        while( fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL)
        {
                /* fgets leaves '\n' in input buffer. ditch it */
                line [strlen(line)-1] = '\0';    

                while (line !=  NULL)
                {
                        //parse command and arg
                        args[0] = strtok(line, " "); //grab command

                        for (i=1; i<MAX_ARG; i++)       //grab arguments, to assume max = 10?
                        {
                                  //if a single command with arguments then set command & argument

                                //for (i>0)
                                {
                                        // check to see if the command is 'exit'
                                        if(!strcmp("exit", args[i]))
                                        {
                                                exit(0);
                                        }
                                        {
                                                int p[2];
                                            pipe(p)

                                            if (fork() == 0) //child
                                            {
                                                    close (0);
                                                    dup(p[0]);
                                                    exec("cmd2");
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                    close(1);
                                                    close(p[0]);
                                                    close(p[1]);
                                                    dup(p[1]);
                                                    exec("cmd1");
                                    }
                                            close(0);
                                            open("stdout.txt", "r");
                                            if (fork()== 0)
                                            {
                                                    exec("cmd3");
                                            }
                                    }
                                    else if (!strcmp(">", args[i]))
                                            open("stderr.txt". "w")
                                            if (fork() == 0)
                                            {
                                                    exec("cmd1");
                                            }

                                    }
                                    else if (!strcmp(">>", args[i]))
                                    {
                                            close(1);
                                            open("stdout_stderr.txt", "w");
                                            if (fork() == 0)
                                            {
                                                    close(2);
                                                    dup(1);
                                                    exec("cmd2");
                                            }

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                            pid = fork();

                                            if (pid == 0)
                                            {
                                                    status = execvp(command,args);
                                                    exit(0);
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                    waitpid(-1);
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The debugger stack trace says?

Comment: `while (line !=  NULL)` Useless nesting. It was the loop condition, remember? (BTW it cannot be NULL since it is the address of an array)

Comment: : In function â€˜mainâ€™:
: error: expected â€˜;â€™ before â€˜ifâ€™
: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
:13: warning: unused variable â€˜statusâ€™
:12: warning: unused variable â€˜pidâ€™
:11: warning: unused variable â€˜commandâ€™

Comment: Something you might want to do: learn to use functions to prevent your code from becoming too messy to read.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few things wrong in your program, so it's hard to point to one line and say change this.  I think you are trying to do too much at once and not building on a solid base.

In programming you want to start small and build on your progress, your professor did you a favor by lining up the steps:

1. read incoming command, parse each part of command
2. fork child process
   and execute each command without (< > >> |)
3. successfully execute
   each command with <, >, >>
4. successfully execute each command with |

Try to get #1 working befor moving on to #2 and as mentioned before using functions is going to help a lot.  I would suggest looking at this post http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/215994-writing-shell-c  which will give you a simple shell you could model from.  Here is a baseline parser to get you started on #1 (based on the post mentioned)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char line[4096] = {0};
char safeline[4096] = {0};
int done = 0;
int i = 0;
char *s = line;
char **t = NULL;
char *prompt = ">";
char *args = NULL;
char *nl = NULL;
int main(void)
{
  while(!done)
  {
    printf("%s", prompt);
    fflush(stdout);
    if(NULL == fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
    {
      t = NULL;
      done = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      nl = strchr(line, '\n');
      if(nl != NULL)
      {
        *nl = '\0';
        strcpy(safeline, line);
      }
      else
      {
        int ch;
        printf("Line too long! Ignored.\n");
        while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
        {
          continue;
        }
        if(ch == EOF)
        {
          done = 1;
        }
      }
      args = strchr(line, ' ');
      if(args != NULL)
      {
        *args++ = '\0';
      }
      if(!done)
      {
        printf("command -  %s :  args - %s\n",s, args);
      }
   }
  }
}
```